# Using draggables to trigger an if statement that .shows() a perviously hidden class

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

so I'm creating a game with jQuery where the user has to place four pictures (draggables) in the correct order to move on to the next level. The part is checking if the pictures are in the right order and if the check is true showing (.show()) a none displayed button (display: none;) with a link to the next game. I think the code will be a little easier to understand.

**HTML**

```
<div class="completion">
        <h1>Way to Go!</h1>
        <p> You beat the game! To play the next game click below</p>
        <p class="nextgame"><a href="TheLatestNewsGame2"> Next Game </a></p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.completion {
display: none;
position: absolute;
```

}

**javascript/jquery**

```
if ($("#game1drop1").hasClass("correct") && $("#game1drop2").hasClass("correct") && $("#game1drop3").hasClass("correct") && $("#game1drop4").hasClass("correct") ) {
      $(".completion").show;
  };
```

**note** all the droppables (#game1drop1) have the correct class I've checked using the console.The code will run a console.log statement as well. So I'm pretty sure the mistake is with my use of the .show() statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**show** is a **function**, so you need to invoke it.

```
$(".completion").show();
```

Comment: Thanks Worked for me, but I also had to turn the element into a block to get the show function to work properly!